# Google sheets query date/time range

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to query approved data that is between 1:00pm the previous business day and 1:00pm today without having to manually enter the dates. I can get it to work for yesterday, but it doesn’t benefit me if yesterday was a weekend or a holiday. I hope there is a way to solve this.

Here is the code I have now.

```
=query({'Source'!$A$2:G}, "SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1=true and Col2 <=timestamp'"
&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd 13:00:00")&"' and Col2 > timestamp'"&text(today)-1,
"yyyy-mm-dd 13:00:00")&"'",0)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet with your expected result? This would help other users to verify the correctness of the answer based on your input data. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

The formula seems fine except for a missing parentheses in `today()`. Try this:

```
=query( 
  Source!A2:G, 
  "select C 
   where A = true 
   and timestamp '" & text(today() - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd 13:00:00") & "' < B
   and B <= timestamp '" & text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd 13:00:00") & "' ",
  0
)
```